# Definite Integral involving Max function.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Here is an integral I was attempting to solve $\int\limits_{0}^{\ln t}{\max{\left(1,x\right)dx}}$ but my answer is not coming to be correct. What is wrong in my attempt?

**Attempt 1.** Let's call the integral $I$

**Case 1.** Let $0<t<e$  $\implies$ $\ln t < 1$

This means the given integral becomes $\int\limits_{0}^{\ln t}{1 dx}$ because from $(0,1)$ the maximum between $1$ and $x$, is $1$  $$\implies I=\ln t \tag{1}$$

**Case 2.** Let $e<t< \infty$ $\implies$ $\ln t >1$

This means the given integral becomes $I= \int\limits_{1}^{\ln t}{\max{\left(1,x\right)dx}} = \int\limits_{1}^{\ln t}x dx$ because from $(0,\infty)$ the maximum between $1$ and $x$, is $x$  $$\implies I=\left[\frac{x^2}{2}\right]_{1}^{\ln t}= \frac{(\ln t)^2-1}{2} \tag{2}$$

Adding $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get $$I = \ln t + \frac{(\ln t)^2-1}{2}$$

**But this is not the correct answer.**

**Attempt 2.** We know that $\max{\left(f(x),g(x)\right)} = \frac{f(x)+g(x)}{2}+\frac{|f(x)-g(x)|}{2}$

Hence $I=\int\limits_{0}^{\ln t}{\max{\left(1,x\right)dx}}=\int\limits_{0}^{\ln t}{(\frac{1+x}{2}+\frac{|1-x|}{2})dx}$

$$\implies \int\limits_{0}^{\ln t}{\frac{1}{2}dx}+\int\limits_{0}^{\ln t}{\frac{x}{2}dx}+\int\limits_{0}^{\ln t}{\frac{|1-x|}{2}dx}$$

The first two integrals will give us $\frac{\ln t}{2} + \frac{(\ln t)^2}{4} \tag{1}$

Let's calculate the third integral $I_3 = \int\limits_{0}^{\ln t}{\frac{|1-x|}{2}dx}$

**Case 1.** Let $0<t<e$  $\implies$ $\ln t < 1$

$I_3 = \int\limits_{0}^{1}{\frac{x-1}{2}dx}=\left[\frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{x}{2}\right]_{0}^{1}=\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{2}=-\frac{1}{4} \tag{2}$

**Case 2.** Let $e<t< \infty$ $\implies$ $\ln t >1$

$I_3 = \int\limits_{1}^{\ln t}{\frac{1-x}{2}dx} = \left[\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{4}\right]_{1}^{\ln t} = \frac{\ln t}{2} - \frac{(\ln t)^2}{4} - \frac{1}{4} \tag{3}$

Adding $(1)$,$(2)$ and $(3)$, we get $$I=\ln t -\frac{1}{2}$$

**But this also is not the correct answer.**

**Please tell me where am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Correct Attempt 1.** Let's call the integral $I$

**Case 1.** Let $0<t\le e$  $\implies$ $\ln t \le 1$

This means the given integral becomes $\int\limits_{0}^{\ln t}{1 dx}$ because from $(0,1)$ the maximum between $1$ and $x$, is $1$  $$\implies I=\ln t \tag{1}$$

**Case 2.** Let $e\le t< \infty$ $\implies$ $\ln t \ge 1$

This means the given integral becomes $\color{red}{I= \int\limits_{0}^{\ln t}{\max{\left(1,x\right)dx}} = \int\limits_{0}^{1}{1 dx} + \int\limits_{1}^{\ln t}x dx}$ because from $(1,\infty)$ the maximum between $1$ and $x$, is $x$  $$\implies I=1 + \left[\frac{x^2}{2}\right]_{1}^{\ln t}= 1 + \frac{(\ln t)^2-1}{2}=\frac{(\ln t)^2+1}{2} \tag{2}$$

We get combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ $$I = \begin{cases} \ln t & \text{if } 0<t \le e, \\ \frac{(\ln t)^2+1}{2} & \text{if } e\le t<\infty. \end{cases}$$

**Correct Attempt 2.** We know that $\max{\left(f(x),g(x)\right)} = \frac{f(x)+g(x)}{2}+\frac{|f(x)-g(x)|}{2}$

Hence $I=\int\limits_{0}^{\ln t}{\max{\left(1,x\right)dx}}=\int\limits_{0}^{\ln t}{(\frac{1+x}{2}+\frac{|1-x|}{2})dx}$

$$\implies \int\limits_{0}^{\ln t}{\frac{1}{2}dx}+\int\limits_{0}^{\ln t}{\frac{x}{2}dx}+\int\limits_{0}^{\ln t}{\frac{|1-x|}{2}dx}$$

The first two integrals will give us $$\frac{\ln t}{2} + \frac{(\ln t)^2}{4} \tag{1}$$

Let's calculate the third integral $I_3 = \int\limits_{0}^{\ln t}{\frac{|1-x|}{2}dx}$

**Case 1.** Let $0<t\le e$  $\implies$ $\ln t \le 1$

$\color{red}{I_3 = \int\limits_{0}^{\ln t}{\frac{1-x}{2}dx}=\left[\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{4}\right]_{0}^{\ln t}=\frac{\ln t}{2} - \frac{(\ln t)^2}{4}} \tag{2}$

**Case 2.** Let $e\le t< \infty$ $\implies$ $\ln t \ge 1$

$$\color{red}{I_3 = \int\limits_{0}^{1}{\frac{1-x}{2}dx} + \int\limits_{1}^{\ln t}{\frac{x-1}{2}dx} = \left[\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{4}\right]_{0}^{1} + \left[\frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{x}{2}\right]_{1}^{\ln t}}$$ $$\implies I_3 = \left[\frac{1}{4}\right] + \left[\frac{(\ln t)^2}{4} - \frac{\ln t}{2} + \frac{1}{4}\right] = \frac{(\ln t)^2}{4} - \frac{\ln t}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \tag{3}$$

Combining $(1)$and$(2)$, and $(1)$and$(3)$ separately, we get $$I = \begin{cases} \ln t & \text{if } 0<t\le e, \\ \frac{(\ln t)^2+1}{2} & \text{if } e\le t<\infty. \end{cases}$$

**Both attempts give us the same solution.**

$\color{red}{\text{The corrections have been pointed out in red.}}$

Comment: Your first case is still wrong, the upper bound of the integral is still $\ln t$.

Comment: You seem to keep on being confused between cases. They are **independent**. Hence, adding (1) and (2) makes no sense.

Comment: @BillO'Haran Am I correct now?

Comment: Yes! Except for the criteria, it should be set on $t$ rather than $x$

Comment: @BillO'Haran All thanks to you!!

Comment: You're welcome, as I have edited my last comment, notice that the criteria on the value of $I$ is on $t$ rather than $x$ (because $x$ does not exist outside the integral).

Comment: @BillO'Haran better?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that now we can say it is perfect. Do not forget to accept your answer so people will know what to look for when reading your post.

Comment: @BillO'Haran I have corrected my second attempt too, please verify it is correct whenever you get free time.

Comment: Seems fine. Again, accept your answer for future readers' sake ;)

Comment: @BillO'Haran I tried to accept but it says "You can accept your own answer in 2 days"

Comment: You'll have to wait then.

Comment: @BillO'Haran: I know that the question is to spot the mistake in the original post. But there are so much easier approaches !

Comment: I most definitely agree but those are the rules of this site. I think you know better than me how frustrating it can be. We can talk about it more in chat if you want to. I'd like to have your views on this.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Are you always interested in finding the fastest solution? The OP can benefit by analysing his mistakes and learning manifolds than just the fastest solution.

Comment: @Vivek: the OP learnt from the answerers. There was no need to duplicate the whole question in an answer, which, by the way, doesn't point at the mistake.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I think it is justified for the OP to give the whole answer with corrections so that other people can learn from the experience. The purpose of this website is to present something that benefit other people too from the mistakes, not just to keep it to yourself. By the way, I have pointed out the corrections, hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

The given function equals $1$, then $x$ for increasing $x$. The corresponding antiderivatives must be $x+C$ and $\dfrac{x^2}2+C'$. To ensure continuity at $x=1$, $C'=C+\dfrac12$.

Hence

$$\int\max(1,x)\,dx=\begin{cases}x\le1\to x+C,\\x\ge1\to\dfrac{x^2+1}2+C.\end{cases}$$

The definite integral follows.

Answer (score 0):

Your reasoning is correct, but you made a small mistake in your first attempt for case 2:

$$ I=\int_0^{\ln t}\max(1,x)dx = \int_0^1\max(1,x)dx + \int_1^{\ln t}\max(1,x)dx = \int_0^11dx + \int_1^{\ln t}xdx$$

I think you understood that completely because you changed the boundaries but you got confused when dealing with case 2. You mustn't add $\ln t$ to $\int_1^{\ln t}xdx$ but 1.

Again, for your second attempt, your reasoning is fine but you got confused because adding (2) and (3) makes no sense since it deals with distinct cases.

Comment: The correct answer is $\frac{(\ln t)^2}{2}+\frac{1}{2}$ how shall I arrive at this in my second attempt?

Comment: Well, as I told you, if you take your first attempt: from your solution, you mustn't add $\ln t$ but 1 so instead of $\frac{\ln^2 t -1}{2} + \ln t$, you have: $\frac{\ln^2 t -1}{2} +1 = \frac{\ln^2 t + 1}{2}$. Note that this is only for $t\geq e$.

Comment: I am asking for second attempt

Comment: Then, $$\int_0^{\ln t} \frac{|1-x|}{2}dx = \int_0^1 \frac{1-x}{2} dx + \int_1^{\ln t} \frac{x-1}{2}dx =  \int_0^1 \frac{1}{2} dx -  \int_0^1 \frac{x}{2} dx + \int_1^{\ln t} \frac{x}{2}dx - \int_1^{\ln t} \frac{1}{2}dx$$. I'll leave the rest to you.

Answer (score 0):

- $x\le 1\implies \max(1,x)=1$, then $\ln t\le1\implies I=\left.x\right|_{x=0}^{\ln t}=\ln t.$
- $x\ge 1\implies \max(1,x)=x$ then $\ln t\ge1\implies I=\left.x\right|_{x=0}^1+\left.\dfrac{x^2}2\right|_{x=1}^{\ln t}=\dfrac{\ln^2t+1}2$.

Comment: can you also tell me what's wrong in my second attempt?

Comment: @Simba: hint: $1$ instead of $\ln t$.